# Error with Android Expresso Testing: More than one library with package name 'android.support.test'

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to integrate Expresso testing into my existing project. But there is a build error keep coming. What does this error message mean? I don't have duplicated packages in my project.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':drawingDesk_Android:processDebugAndroidTestResources'.
> Error: more than one library with package name 'android.support.test'
```

I have already gone through all my modules and tried to remove conflicting libraries. But error is still the same.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.axis.drawingdesk.v3"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled = true
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled false
        testInstrumentationRunner = 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/xml'] } }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}


dependencies {
    compile files('libs/FlurryAnalytics-6.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/adcolony.jar')
    compile project(':unity-ads')
    compile project(':photopickerlib')
    compile files('libs/ofandroidlib.jar')
    compile files('libs/axis-drawing-engine.jar')
    compile project(':axisiaplib')
    compile project(':viewpagerindicator')
    compile project(':colorpickerlib')
    compile project(':coloringbook')
    compile files('libs/zip4j_1.3.2.jar')
    compile project(':stickerlayer')
    compile project(':filedownloader')
    compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.circular-progress-button:library:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.github.sd6352051:NiftyNotification:1.2'
    compile 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.3.0'
    compile 'io.paperdb:paperdb:1.1'
    compile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.2.1'
    compile 'com.zsoltsafrany:needle:1.0.0'
    compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.4'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    compile 'com.nightonke:jellytogglebutton:1.0.2'

    compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.1'

    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1"

    compile project(':cropper')

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.0.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.0.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

remove below line from your code, it'll work

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```